# Assigning typeform to iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-lifecycle, typeform

I made a code editor in `reactJS` and I'm trying to write the Typeform code so that I'll see the output in the `iframe`. If I assign the value to the `iframe` in the `render()` or in `componentDidUpdate()` or `shouldComponentUpdate()` or in any other helping function the contents of the iframe do not come.

But if I refresh the page and assign the value coming from my database in the `componentDidMount()`, the contents of iframe comes and are showing me expected results.

My requirement is to assign the value to iframe in any helping function, but by doing so the contents of `iframe` do not come, and I'm getting the white screen in this case. All other sorts of code are working well and giving me the required results in the iframe except the Typeform code.

Any idea of how can I overcome this problem?

My Typeform code is:

```
<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://form.typeform.com/to/gWfKQXJg" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div> <script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)) { js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() </script>
```

Comment: You need to use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between frames

Comment: @yunzen use postMessage to update the iframe value?

Comment: What IS the `value` of the iframe?

Comment: @yunzen thanks for your reply. I mentioned the value in the question.

Comment: You typed in value three times. But I don't know what the value is?

Comment: `<div class="type.....})() </script>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I think I cannot help you without a working demonstration of your issue

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to embed a typeform in your React app?
if so you can use the [react-typeform-embed package](https://github.com/alexgarces/react-typeform-embed)

and just use it like this in your project

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ReactTypeformEmbed } from 'react-typeform-embed';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ReactTypeformEmbed url="https://demo.typeform.com/to/njdbt5" />;
  }
}
```